# EF4: Joining Entity Query on IEnumerable list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have two IEnumerables:

```
IEnumerable<ThisEmployee> thisEmployees;
IEnumerable<ThatEmployee> thatEmployees;
```

They are populated from 2 separate contexts. ThisEmployee and ThatEmployee are not matching types. They don't share anything similar apart from an EmployeeNumber property.

I want to get all ThatEmployee.Notes for any employee in thatEmployees that has a matching EmployeeNumber in thisEmployees.

I can't for the life of me work out how.

Comment: I think a LINQ join query could be used since it supports `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its in two different contexts try using ToList to get all objects. Then using Linq to Objects u can use `Where(r => thisEmployees.Any(s => s.EmployeeNumber == r.EmployeeNumber))`. Not sure if i understood u correctly :)

Comment: My implementation used this syntax, which I am more comfortable with but the idea is exactly the same. Thanks!

var selected = (from ta in thatEmployees
                join ti in thisEmployees on ta.Username equals ti.UserName
                select ta).ToList();

Comment: That wouldn't work according to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a90b903-93b6-4894-8ed5-0ae1521235bb/join-on-entity-and-ienumerable?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 2):

Your collections come from different contexts so get ids of employees first in linq-to-objects:

```
 var ids = from e1 in thatEmployees
           join e2 in thisEmployees on e1.EmployeeNumber equals e2.EmployeeNumber
           select e1.Id;
```

Now use ids to get `Notes` from the database in single query

```
 var notes = from n in context.Notes
             where ids.Contains(n.Employee.Id)
             select n;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var notes = thatEmployees
    .Join(thisEmployees,
          ta => ta.EmployeeNumber,
          ti => ti.EmployeeNumber,
          (ta, ti) => ta.Notes)
```